# Java EC-Schnorr Implementation

Tags: signature

I'm trying to write an EC-Schnorr implementation, as described in the following BIP: https://github.com/sipa/bips/blob/bip-schnorr/bip-schnorr.mediawiki

I have the following code for generating a signature using Java & BouncyCastle:

```
public SchnorrSig sign(byte[] hash) {
        MessageDigest md = new SHA256.Digest();
        /* Hash private key & message hash, convert to int mod order */
        BigInteger k = bytesToBigInteger(md.digest(merge(privkey, hash))).mod(order);

        /* Use k value as deterministic nonce for R point */
        ECPoint R = G.multiply(k).normalize();

        /* Checks if R is a quadratic residue (?) */
        while (jacobi(R.getAffineYCoord().toBigInteger()) != 1) {
            k = (order.subtract(k));
            R = G.multiply(k).normalize();
        }

        md = new SHA256.Digest();
        /* Hashes x-coord of R + public key point x coord + message hash, converts to int mod order */
        BigInteger e = bytesToBigInteger(md.digest(merge(bigIntegerToBytes(R.getAffineXCoord().toBigInteger()), Hex.decode("03"), pubkey, hash))).mod(order);

        /* Returns R point + (k e*priv) mod order */
        return new SchnorrSig(R, k.add(e.multiply(bytesToBigInteger(privkey))).mod(order));
    }
```

However it's not matching any of the test vectors provided in the proposal. The public key and R point are being correctly calculated as far as I can tell, but the e value, which then becomes the s, does not appear to be correctly calculated and I can't figure out why.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Taking your word that `R` is OK (although the rationale for the `Checks if R is a quadratic residue` thing evades me), your code for `e` does not seem to emulate `e = sha256(R[0].to_bytes(32, byteorder="big") + bytes_point(point_mul(G, seckey)) + msg)`of the reference code. 1) You seem to hash a hash, where the original seems to hash a message. 2) I do not see where your code gets the 32-byte size of the X coordinate, except if that's burned into `bigIntegerToBytes`. 3) `Hex.decode("03"), pubkey` works only if `pubkey`is an X-coordinate on 32 bytes and the matching Y is odd.

Comment: @fgrieu from what I understood in the description on that GitHub link, the "message" is always a 32 byte array, hence I'm assuming that's a hash of the actual message.

Comment: Maybe you could ask the authors of the proposal to provide test vectors for all intermediate stages in the computation too?

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage I just put in a request, hopefully they'll update it with those values

Comment: are you sure that the '03' prefix is correct here?

Comment: @Cryptostase no, but 02 as a prefix also provides an incorrect result

Comment: probably no prefix , because it is not a public point

Comment: @Cryptostase the point you're talking about is the pubkey, and from what I understand of the reference implementation, it has a prefix.

Comment: This surprises me a bit, because standards like ISO 14888-3 do not include that prefix.

Comment: I suspect that both `Hex.decode("02"), pubkey,` and `Hex.decode("03"), pubkey,` lead to wrong results (it is hard to be sure because we do not know the format or even length of `pubkey`from the question). For point compression as in the reference code, somewhat the point corresponding to `pubkey` must be separated into X and Y coordinates, Y _replaced_ by a `02`or `03` prefix depending on if Y is even or odd, and X expressed as exactly 32 bytes, big-endian. To be answerable the question would need to be migrated to SO, and come with more code (`bytesToBigInteger`) and data (`pubkey`).

Comment: @fgrieu you were right - the point compression was the issue. Now that I've fixed it, everything appears to be working as intended. Also, my apologies for posting the question here instead of in SO.